# Numbers becoming symbols in equation

Tags: equations, symbols

I am trying to write a simple equation: G=log(base 2) (R)

but when I write this in latex:

```
\begin{equation}
\cal{G} = \log_{2}(\cal{R})
\end{equation}
```

the number 2 becomes a symbol:

[image: number turns into symbol]

Any ideas?

Comment: use `\mathcal` not `\cal`. The later is a switch, not a macro taking arguments.